# ¿Cuál es el verdadero origen de la expresión "con la Iglesia hemos topado"?

Tags: expresiones, historia, literatura

De vez en cuando leo la expresión "con la Iglesia hemos topado", para dar a entender cuando la Iglesia o alguna otra entidad importante se interpone en el camino de una empresa a acometer. Se intenta dar así a entender que cuando dicha entidad entra en juego tu empresa corre el riesgo de retrasarse o incluso de irse a pique.

En muchas ocasiones veo que se cita el Quijote como origen de la expresión:

> *En el actual rifirrafe Iglesia-Estado mucho me temo que Aznar no pueda utilizar su draconiano apotegma: "El que no está conmigo está contra mí". Hasta hay ministros que hablan incluso de suprimir en la declaración de la Renta la casilla del 0,5% a favor de la Iglesia, cosa que me parecería justa y razonable aunque escasamente verosímil. Ya habrá algún otro ministro que le recuerde a Aznar lo que en cierta ocasión le dijo Don Quijote a su escudero: "Sancho, con la Iglesia hemos topado".*
>
> Canarias 7, 07/03/2001 : CONTRA ESTO Y AQUELLO

Sin embargo, me ha dado por buscar la expresión en el Quijote y lo que he encontrado es esto:

> *Guió don Quijote, y habiendo andado como docientos pasos, dio con el bulto que hacía la sombra, y vio una gran torre, y luego conoció que el tal edificio no era alcázar, sino la iglesia principal del pueblo. Y dijo:*
>
> *—Con la iglesia hemos dado, Sancho.*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "Segunda parte del ingenioso caballero don Quijote de la Mancha", 1615 (España).

Es decir, en el *Quijote* se usa *iglesia* (con minúscula) porque se refiere a un edificio. Mientras que en la expresión actual se dice *Iglesia* (con mayúscula) porque se refiere a la entidad, y además se cambia el verbo.

En algún momento debió tergiversarse la frase y se comenzó a usar en su sentido actual. ¿En qué momento ocurrió eso? ¿O realmente Cervantes usó la frase con el doble sentido de implicar tanto "dar con el edificio de la iglesia" como "toparse con la Iglesia" igual que en el sentido actual? ¿Se usaba pues ya entonces la frase con el mismo sentido que ahora?

---

El ejemplo más antiguo que he encontrado en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España:

> *La Rusia nos parece haber tomado mejor camino para sus propósitos, como se deja ver por la conducta resuelta y enérgica de los prelados de la iglesia griega
>   cismática, en los Principados la dominante, y de la cual, no lo olvidaremos, es el Czar pontífice y cabeza. Estamos por decirle al principe Vogórides lo que D. Quijote á Sancho en el Toboso: «¡Con la Iglesia hemos topado!» pero como S. E. moldava no ha de hacer caso de nuestros consejos, mas vale dejarlo.*
>
> La América (Madrid). 24/7/1857, página 3.

Comment: Leyendo la frase en su contexto no parece que tenga una doble intención, yo diría que es totalmente literal. El tema está en descubrir en que momento toma forma la expresión tal y como la conocemos

Answer (score 3):

Muy extrañamente, en el CORDE no hay más que un puñado de registros de la expresión *"hemos topado"* y ninguno (¡ni uno solo!) de la frase completa *"con la iglesia hemos topado"*. Tampoco nadie parece saber en qué momento la versión popular de la frase mudó de palabra y de significado. Wikipedia le dedica [un artículo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Con_la_iglesia_hemos_topado) donde recoge varias opiniones, todas negativas con respecto a que Cervantes haya pretendido decir algo más que lo literal.

Un comentarista [menciona](https://vanguardia.com.mx/articulo/con-la-iglesia-hemos-topado-sancho) que

> En la magnífica edición conmemorativa del IV centenario de la
>   aparición de la I Parte de El Quijote, publicada en 2005 por la Real
>   Academia Española, ésta indica que la frase ha de leerse como: “Hemos
>   encontrado la iglesia”. Y agrega la siguiente nota: “Con la
>   sustitución de ‘dado’ por ‘topado’, y de forma totalmente extraña al
>   contexto del Quijote, la frase se ha proverbializado para indicar  que
>   la Iglesia o una autoridad se interpone en la realización de un
>   proyecto”.
>
> Por otra parte, no he encontrado nota alguna sobre este punto en las
>   ediciones de El Quijote comentadas por Vicente de los Ríos y Juan
>   Antonio Pellicer, ambos del siglo XVIII, como tampoco en la de Diego
>   Clemencín, que es de principios del siglo XIX.

Esto último podría indicar que ni de los Ríos y Pellicer en el s. XVIII ni Clemencín en el s. XIX conocían la sustitución popular, o bien la conocían pero no la consideraron tan importante como para aclarar el punto, o incluso que la misma no existía todavía... pero la ausencia de evidencia no es evidencia de ausencia, claro.

El comentario negativo de [Francisco Rodríguez Marín](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Rodr%C3%ADguez_Mar%C3%ADn) (donde habla de "ridículos intérpretes esoteristas del Quijote") se refiere a una edición comentada de 1927.

La intención real de Cervantes al mencionar la iglesia del pueblo es imposible de determinar. Para mí es sugestivo que el pasaje continúe con Sancho diciendo

> "...plega a Dios que no demos con nuestra sepultura, que no es buena señal andar por los cimenterios a tales horas..."

En esa época los camposantos estaban junto a las iglesias, de manera que lo que dice Sancho sobre el cementerio es totalmente atinado, y también es propio del genio del personaje hacer un juego de asociación con la muerte, más todavía dado lo supersticioso del ambiente. De ahí a leer una crítica a la Iglesia Católica hay mucho trecho, aunque quizá Cervantes contaba con eso.